# Laravel eloquent group eloquent records in hourinterval with Left join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

I'm using laravel v8 and i have two tables with structure like this:

**orders**

| id | total | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 2022-01-01 11:00:05 |
| 2 | 300 | 2022-01-01 15:00:05 |
| .. | .. | ... |

**order_items**

| id | order_id | product_id | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 4 | 3 |
| .. | .. | .. | .. |

i want to generate a report which consist of the summary of order in every hour (59 minutes 59 seconds) interval in one day, for example like this:

| Date | Time | Total Order | Total Order Item Quantity | Total Order Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan 01 2020 | 00:00 - 00:59 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jan 01 2020 | 01:00 - 01:59 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jan 01 2020 | 02:00 - 02:59 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Jan 01 2020 | 03:00 - 03:59 | 1 | 2 | 80 |
| Jan 01 2020 | 04:00 - 04:59 | 3 | 10 | 500 |
| Jan 01 2020 | 05:00 - 0:59 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ............ | .............. | ... | ... | ... |
| Jan 01 2020 | 21:00 - 21:59 | 5 | 18 | 1020 |
| Jan 01 2020 | 22:00 - 22:59 | 1 | 5 | 210 |
| Jan 01 2020 | 23:00 - 0:59 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Currently i need to select every interval like this and then doing foreach loop to get summarize the data for the interval:

```
$orders = DB::table('orders')
            ->select(
                [
                    DB::RAW('orders.total as total'),
                    DB::RAW('order_items.quantity as quantity')
                ]
            )
            ->leftJoin ('order_items. AS order_items.', function ($query) {
                $query->on('order_items..order_id', '=', 'orders.id'); 
            })
            ->whereBetween('orders.created_at',[date('Y-m-d 00:00:00'),date('Y-m-d 00:59:59')]) 
             ->get();

$totalOrder = $orders->count();
$totalQuantity = 0;
$totalAmount = 0;
foreach($orders as $order){
   $totalQuantity += $order->quantity;
   $totalAmount += $order->total;
}

$data['00:00 - 00:59'] = [
  'total_order' => $totalOrder,
  'total_quantity' => $totalQuantity,
  'total_amount' => $totalAmount,
];
```

this solution is working but it's not very effecient , how can i run a single query database to achieve this kind of result ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an alias and `group by`:

```php
$orders = DB::table('orders')
    ->select(
        [
            DB::RAW('left(orders.created_at,13) as hour'),
            DB::RAW('sum(orders.total) as total'),
            DB::RAW('sum(order_items.quantity) as quantity')
        ]
    )
    ->leftJoin('order_items', 'order_items.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
    ->groupBy('hour')
    ->get();
```

Comment: isn't using hour will hold for full 1 hour for example 00:00:00 - 01:00:00 , what i want is 00:00:00 - 00:59:59

Comment: It'll do what you want. `left(orders.created_at,13)` will return `'2022-01-01 11'`, i.e. `2022-01-01 11:00:00` to `2022-01-01 11:59:59`

Comment: The results only show the hour which the data exists, it does not show the hour where the data is not exists

Comment: Just use a loop to show the empty records.